# UDP RAW_SOCKET packets to itself are captured on loopback interface instead of eth0

Tags: c, linux, sockets, raw-sockets

Using sources from this article [RAW_SOCKET to forge UDP packets](http://nunix.fr/index.php/programmation/1-c/58-rawsocket-to-forge-udp-packets) I am generating packets from other host to own eth0 ip address, as example, 192.168.10.1 --> 192.168.10.131.

But tcpdump shows, that packets are arriving into lo, not eth0...
on lo -

```
10:10:18.332284 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 768, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
192.168.10.1.57961 > 192.168.10.131.12001: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 43
```

and on eth0 is silence.

How to change the code, to make packets arrive into eth0?
[direct link to C source file](http://nunix.fr/attachments/nunix.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you have to use tcp functions instead of udp

For UDP you can set the optname to SO_BINDTODEVICE

```
const char device[] = "eth0";
rc=setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, device, sizeof(device));
if (rc != 0) 
{
 printf ("%s: could not set SO_BINDTODEVICE (%s)\n",
    argv[0], strerror(errno));
 exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Take a look to http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/setsockoptman.html

Comment: it's anyway on lo...
`tcpdump -i lo -nn -vv -XX -s 4096 'udp and port 12001'
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 4096 bytes
11:51:15.406405 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 128)
    192.168.10.1.12002 > 192.168.10.131.12001: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 100
 0x0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800 4500  ..............E.
 0x0010:  0080 0000 4000 4011 a498 c0a8 0a01 c0a8  ....@.@.........`

Comment: Anyway, it's working for me, after testing. Even if i see it on lo, packets are reaching iptables routing & NAT tables, NATting and passing to real destinations behind eth1!